# How to post the CKEDITOR value along with other inputs via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ckeditor

I have a partial view in my asp.net core project and I want to post all `input` and `select` and `editor` values to controller with AJAX.
I can post all `input` and `select` tag to controller but can't post CkEditor value.

Of course I can get the CkEditor value in jQuery, but can't select it.

**Partial View:**

```
@model LibraryProject.Models.ViewModels.AddEditBookViewModel

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input asp-for="BookName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookDescription" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <textarea id="BookDescription" name="BookDescription" asp-for="BookDescription" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace('BookDescription');
                </script>

            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookGroupID" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <select asp-for="BookGroupID" asp-items="@Model.BookGroups" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AuthorID" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <select asp-for="AuthorID" asp-items="@Model.Authors" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookPageCount" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input asp-for="BookPageCount" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="button" id="submitinfo" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Book" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**And My jQuery Code:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#submitinfo', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var fileupload = $("#files").get(0);
        var files = fileupload.files;
        var data = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('files', files[i]);
        }

//In this line I can get editor value
        var editorval = CKEDITOR.instances['BookDescription'].getData();

//***here i can post all input and select tag value but can`t post editor value along with other
        $('input,select').each(function (x, y) {
            data.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddBook", "Book")',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {
                alert(res.message);
            } else {
                $.each(res.errors, function (a, b) {
                    alert(b);
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, b, error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now how can I post Editor value along with other where it is marked with 3 stars in the jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value from CKEditor and add it to the form data.

```
$('input,select').each(function (x, y) {
     data.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
});
var editorval = CKEDITOR.instances['BookDescription'].getData();
data.append('BookDescription',editorval);
```